# How to get a billing custom field from WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get a custom billing field from my WooCommerce order? For example I've WooCommerce Germanized installed which adds a custom billing field named `vat_id`.

I've found a function `get_address_prop()` in the WooCommerce orders class but this function is protected so I can't call it with `$order->get_address_prop()`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but for billing custom fields (or shipping custom fields or any custom field), simply use the `WC_Data` method `get_meta()` with the correct meta key on the `$order` object instance or also WordPress `get_post_meta()` with the correct meta key from the order Id…

Comment: For germanized "vat_id" simply use `$vat_id = $order->get_meta('_billing_vat_id');`

Answer (score 0):

This is my function I've created to retrieve any custom billing field I want:

```
/**
 * Returns a custom billing field value
 *
 * @param object $order
 * @param string $custom_field
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_custom_billing_field( object $order, string $custom_field ): string {
    $order_data       = $order->get_data();
    $custom_field_val = '';

    if ( ! empty( $order_data ) && isset( $order_data['billing'][ $custom_field ] ) ) {
        $custom_field_val = $order_data['billing'][ $custom_field ];
    }

    return apply_filters( 'get_custom_billing_field', $custom_field_val );
}
```

This is an example call for retrieving the `vat_id` set in WooCommerce Germanized Pro:

```
$order = wc_get_order( 22 );

get_custom_billing_field( $order, 'vat_id' );
```

I hope this helps someone. If you got a better idea, please let me know.